# Speed up Data.Array row extraction and filtering

Tags: arrays, haskell

I have a very simple function in my application that does a lot of work and occupies the most computation time:

```
f :: Int -> Array (Int,Int) Int -> [Int]
f x arr = [v | v <- range (l,u), vv <- [g!(x,v)], vv /= 0]
          where ((_,l), (_,u)) = bounds arr
```

What this does is: extract a row at index `x` from the array `arr` and return all the column indices with elements `\= 0`. So, for instance, given the following matrix with bounds `((0,0),(2,2))`:

```
arr =  [[0, 0, 5], 
        [4, 0, 3],
        [0, 3, 1]]   -- for simplicity in [[a]] notation
```

the expected output is

```
f 0 arr == [2] 
f 1 arr == [0,2]
f 2 arr == [1,2]
```

How do I speed up `f` and profile with more detail what actually takes most of the computation time in f (list construction, array access, etc)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f x arr = [v | v <- range (l,u), vv <- [g!(x,v)], vv /= 0]
```

I suppose `g` is a typo, it should be `arr`.
Instead of `range (l,u)` use `[l .. u]`, the compiler may be able to  optimise the former as well as the latter, but `[l .. u]` is more idiomatic (and maybe the compiler can't optimise the former as well).
Don't create a pointless one-element list, you can use the direct test,

```
f x arr = [v | v <- [l .. u], arr!(x,v) /= 0]
```

The compiler may again be able to rewrite the former to the latter, but a) the latter is much clearer, and b) doesn't risk that the compiler can't.

To find out where time is spent, you can insert cost-centre annotations,

```
f x arr = [v | v <- {-# SCC "Range" #-} [l .. u], {-# SCC "ZeroTest" #-} (arr!(x,v) /= 0)]
```

but such annotations disable many optimisations (compiling for profiling always does), so the picture you get from profiling can be skewed and differ from what actually happens in the optimised programme.

Comment: I just checked the libraries source and `range` should be the same as `[..]`.

Comment: @sclv Yes, it's the same. It's however one more layer the compiler has to peel off. Should be no problem with `Int`, but may be for other types.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This did indeed help quite a bit and I think that the problem is the construction of the list. What I actually need in the end is a fold over the list, so it might be better to do the fold over the array directly in the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Here is documentation on profiling:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/profiling.html

And a book chapter:

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html

If your code turns out to be slow because of array updates, use `Data.Vector.*` from [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package.